# Filling a column with data obtained by comparing data from another column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table. I'm creating a new column "Timing". And I need to fill it with numbers, depending on what data is in the column "type". For example, if in the cell of the column "type" is dgv, then in the column "timing" there should be a number 17, if ds, then 8, if psp, then 3, etc. In total there are several conditions.

[part of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g6Ff.png)
and so on

My code:

```
import csv

with open('C:/Notebook/data1.txt','r') as csvinput:
    with open('C:/Notebook/datawr1.txt', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Timing') # Here I create a column "Timing"
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:  #I think here should be a condition if
            row.append(' ') 
            all.append(row)           


        writer.writerows(all)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary `d`, if not match get `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['dgv','ds','psp', 'a']})
print (df)
  type
0  dgv
1   ds
2  psp
3    a

d = {'dgv':17,'ds':8,'psp':3}
df['Timing'] = df['type'].map(d)
print (df)
  type  Timing
0  dgv    17.0
1   ds     8.0
2  psp     3.0
3    a     NaN
```

EDIT:

In pandas for reading files is use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), for writing [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (no problem if it is .txt file):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""code,type,date,quantity
0,dgv,07.11.2016,1
0,dgv,08.06.2016,1
0,ds,01.07.2016,1
0,ds,03.08.2016,1
0,ds,03.08.2016,1
0,psp,06.03.2016,1
0,a,07.08.2016,1"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
   code type        date  quantity
0     0  dgv  07.11.2016         1
1     0  dgv  08.06.2016         1
2     0   ds  01.07.2016         1
3     0   ds  03.08.2016         1
4     0   ds  03.08.2016         1
5     0  psp  06.03.2016         1
6     0    a  07.08.2016         1
```

---

```
d = {'dgv':17,'ds':8,'psp':3}
df['Timing'] = df['type'].map(d)
print (df)
   code type        date  quantity  Timing
0     0  dgv  07.11.2016         1    17.0
1     0  dgv  08.06.2016         1    17.0
2     0   ds  01.07.2016         1     8.0
3     0   ds  03.08.2016         1     8.0
4     0   ds  03.08.2016         1     8.0
5     0  psp  06.03.2016         1     3.0
6     0    a  07.08.2016         1     NaN

df.to_csv('myfile.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the problem is that there is a lot of data in the file. The file is in .txt format. And the file is different every time. I wanted the code to read the file and add the column "Timing" and fill it. I do not understand how to refer to a column "type" as a dateframe.